# How to chain methods after already returning a value?

Tags: javascript

The following does work:

```
//Returns an object with an "id" of 1, which is inside another object, "collection".
//Then, calls .move(), which sets collection's property "coordinates" to {x: 20, y: 20}

collection.get(1).move(20,20);

console.log(collection.get(1).get('coordinates')); //returns { x: 20, y: 20 }
```

This works because the *collection .get()* method executes **return this;**
Therefore, that method is chainable.

However, this does not work:

```
collection.get(1) //returns the object inside "collection" that has an "id" of 1
.get('coordinates') //returns that object's current "coordinates" { x: 20, y: 20 }
.move(20,20); //error
```

This is because the *"object with id: 1" .get()* method looks similar to this:

```
Thing.prototype = {
    id: null,
    get: function(prop) {
            if (prop == 'id') {
                return this.id; 
            } else {
                return this.attributes[prop];
            }
         } 
    }
```

(The id is set when an object Thing is initialized, by the way.) As you can see, this individual .get() method already returns a value (a certain property of its object).
Therefore, given the way the code is set up now, the method isn't chainable.

To kind of wrap it all up a little bit, my "collections" hold an array of "things".  Each *collection* has a *.get() method*, which returns a *thing* from the *collection's* array of *things*.  In addition, each *thing* has a *.get() method*, which returns a value from a specific property in that *thing*.

The issue I'm having is that if possible, I'd like to make the indiviual *thing .get() method* chainable... but, I can't call both of these lines of code in the same block:

```
return this[prop];
return this;
```

I've looked at, for example, a code excerpt from [one of John Resig's slides](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#2):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
  var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift(); 
  return function(){ 
    return fn.apply(object, 
      args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
  }; 
};
```

which shows an example of returning a couple different things through the use of callback functions (I think).

I've tried several different ways of going about this, which didn't work, including returning an object of another method with a callback that returns the object.

Any pushes in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You're already terminating the chain using `.get('coordinates')`, which does not return the same collection. You can't chain from there anymore.

Comment: The object that you return from your method is the object that will be used for the next method call when chaining.  So, you have to return an object that has methods in order to continue chaining after this method.  So, it's incompatible to return an id and then expect chaining to continue to work.  Javascript will tell you that the id value you returned isn't an object or doesn't have the `.move()` method.

Comment: Why are you calling `get("coordinates")` if you don't want to do something with the coordinates, but instead want to do more things with the object? This whole question seems misguided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can only return one thing. If it's purpose is to return data *about* the object, it can't also return the object itself. You can only chain methods that are used for their side effects or to return related collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about performing operations on sub-objects, you could look to jQuery's [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) and [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) for inspiration. That said, I'm not sure it's very good API design; the usage is much more clear if you just put an intermediate result in a variable and use multiple statements, even if that's not so ‘slick’.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that your function must return the object itself if you wish to keep the chain going; this is one way to do that:

```
get: function(prop, callback) {
        if (prop == 'id') {
            callback(this.id);
        } else {
            callback(this.attributes[prop]);
        }
        return this;
     }
```

This makes it chainable again because the side effect of the data fetch is now isolated, but as a result the logic may look a bit funny:

```
collection.get(1)
  .get('coordinates', function(value) {
     // whatever
  })
  .move(20,20);
```